# search bar isnt retaining when i backspace

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have made a search bar and i am able to filter through and search my data. the problem begins when i backspace and try to search for someone else.  i understand that i have to store the filtered data because everytime i filter it brings back new data. how can i go about doing this ? i have my code in this attached as well.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card";
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import { Input } from "@material-ui/core";

function StudentProfiles() {

  const [info, setInfo] = useState();
  const [input, setInput] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {

    fetch("https://api.hatchways.io/assessment/students")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => setInfo(json.students))
  }, []);

  /*const average = (array) => array.reduce((a,b) => a + b )/ array.length;*/
  const filterChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const target = e.target.value;
    setInput(target);

    if (input !== '') {
      const result = info && info.filter((user) => {
        return user.firstName.toLowerCase().startsWith(input.toLowerCase());
      });
      setInfo(result);
    } if (input !== '') {
      const result = info && info.filter((person) => {
        return person.lastName.toLowerCase().startsWith(input.toLowerCase());
      });
      setInfo(result);
    }
    else {
      setInfo(info && info);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Card className="card">
        <CardContent className="scrollbar scrollbar-primary mt-5 mx-auto">
          <Input
            className="searchBar"
            icon="search"
            placeholder="Search by name"
            onChange={filterChange}
            value={input}
          />

          {info && info.map((name) => (
            <ul className="border" key={name.id}>
              <Grid item xs={3} sm={6} md={12} style={{ display: "flex", gap: "3.5rem", paddingBottom: "8px" }}>
                <img alt="" src={name.pic} className="picture"></img>
                <Grid container style={{ display: "inline" }} align="left" justifyContent="flex-end" alignItems="flex-start">
                  <Grid className="studentNames">
                    <span>{name.firstName + " " + name.lastName}</span>
                  </Grid>
                  <span>{name.email}</span>
                  <br />
                  <span>{name.company}</span>
                  <br />
                  <span>{name.skill}</span>
                  <br />
                  <span>Average: {88.66}%</span>
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
            </ul>
          ))}

        </CardContent>
      </Card>
    </div>
  )
}

export default StudentProfiles;
```

Comment: You'll need to store the filtered array in a different state

Answer (score 0):

You can make another state for filtered data and display it.

```
const [filtered, setFiltered] = useState([]);
```

Just change the setInfo for setFiltered.

Comment: so i would replace my mapping method ? or add the new state to it?

Comment: Map over the filtered state. By default it should be set to whole data and when somene types in bar it changes in your filterChange method (info.filter(=> ...)). When bar is empty setFiltered(info)

Comment: okay the search bar works now thank you i just have to allow the page to display the data without pressing space on search bar.